# NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.maximumSize(J)

Tags: java, caching, plugins, bukkit

I seem to be having a problem which only applied to 1 fellow user of a minecraft plugin of mine.

`[15:54:14 ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling <Plugin> v1.0.8 (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.maximumSize(J)Lcom/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder;`

Is there any reason as to why this is happening or if I can over come it some way?

My code:

```
private LoadingCache<String, String> profileCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().
        maximumSize(500).
        expireAfterWrite(4, TimeUnit.HOURS).
        build(new CacheLoader<String, String>() {
            public String load(String name) {
                try {
                    return getProfileJson(name);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Bukkit.getLogger().info("Error, " + e.getLocalizedMessage() + ".");
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the libraries into the exported jar. By default they are not included in the exported Jar as the IDE assumes they are present at runtime, which they are not.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934524/gradle-compile-dependencies-not-included-in-jar) for Gradle and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729054/including-dependencies-in-a-jar-with-maven) for Maven.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` is thrown at runtime because the JVM does not find the method in the referenced class. This typically happens because you are using different versions of a third party library for compiling and running the application.

Check the version of the library used for compiling and the version used for running the code and make sure they match or are at least compatible.